# Consulta con filtro a ldap desde php

Tags: php, ldap

Tengo el siguiente código para autenticar usuarios desde php contra el directorio ldap.

```
$ldap_host      = "10.1.24.3"; // nombre del host o servidor
    $ldap_port      = 389; // puerto del LDAP en el servidor
    $ldap_dn        = 'cn=admin,dc=pinarx,dc=pri,dc=jovenclub,dc=cu';
    $ldap_pass_user = 'ldapadmin';
    // conexion a ldap
    $ldap_conn      = ldap_connect( $ldap_host, $ldap_port ); 
    ldap_set_option($ldap_conn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
    $ldap_bind      = ldap_bind( $ldap_conn, $ldap_dn, $ldap_pass_user );
    if ($ldap_bind){
     //realizo la busquedad
     $filtro="(&(uid=$login_user)(userpassword=$pass_user))";
     $solonecesito = array( "uid");
     $sr=ldap_search($ldap_conn,"dc=pinarx,dc=pri,dc=jovenclub,dc=cu", $filtro, $solonecesito);
    $info = ldap_get_entries($ldap_conn, $sr);
    for ($i=0; $i<$info["count"]; $i++){ 
     $_SESSION['login_user'] = $info[$i]["uid"][0] ."";
    }
}
```

El problema que me surge es que en el filtro que establezco, no me funciona, y lo quiero que haga es que busque exactamente el usuario por su login y password, si le quito el filtro del password, me funciona bien, pero entonces no me valida que la clave del usuario sea correcta, por eso, además del login quiero que chequee que el password sea el correcto.

¿Podría alguien decirme que es lo que tengo mal o que tengo que agregar?

Answer (score 0):

he chequeado el código sustituyendo el atributo USERPASSWORD por otro y me funciona correctamente, pero no logro hacer que funciones con el campo userpassword, lo paso a la consulta encriptado con la misma función de ldap, y no me resulta, no se ha que se debe
lo hice de esta forma:

```
$clave=md5($pass_user);
$filtro="(&(uid=$login_user)(userpassword=$clave))";
```